# How to convert a nested for loop to a declarative statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Using functional methods such as map,filter,reduce, how can a nested for loop that is imperative be converted to a declarative function. Using the below as an example:

```
getTxns: function () {
    var txnsToCheck = [];
    var pages = this.data;
    for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
        var page = pages[i];
        var txns = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < page.txns.length; j++) {
            if (page.txns[j].grade) {
                txnsToCheck.push({ page: i, txn: j, virtual: false });
        }
        else {
            txnsToCheck.push({ page: i, txn: 0, virtual: true });
        }
    }

    return txnsToCheck;
},
```

Below is non working attempt at a functional rewrite, the last map does not work, but I believe illustrates the intent, which is a conditional assignment.

```
getTxns: function () {
    return this.data.
        map(function (page) {
            return page.txns.
                map(function(txn){
                    if (txn.grade){
                        return {page: txn.page_idx, txn: page.txns.indexOf(txn), virtual: false}
                    } else {
                        return {page: txn.page_idx, txn: 0, virtual: true}
        }
    })
})
```

I have considered filter, but its not clear if you can traverse back up the chain for a second filter and map in one operation?

Wondering what a working declarative version of the for loop looks like.

Here is an example of what the data schema looks like:

```
"derived": [
  {
    "page_idx": 0,
    "page_image_url": "",
    "doc_pk": 123456,
    "txns": [
      {
        "page_idx": 0,
        "grade": 0,
        "explanation": "test 1",
        "id": 1962754,
      },
      {
        "page_idx": 0,
        "is_recurring": false,
        "bank_account_pk": null,
        "grade": 0,
        "explanation": "test 2",
        "id": 1962753,
      },
   ]
  },
  {
    "page_idx": 1,
    "page_image_url": "",
    "doc_pk": 2654321,
    "txns": []
  },
  {
    "page_idx": 2,
    "page_image_url": "",
    "doc_pk": 123457,
    "txns": []
  }
]
```

Comment: Looks like you want a flatMap. You can implement it with `reduce`.

Answer (score 2):

What @eclanrs has mentioned can look like this

```
getTxns: function () {
    return this.data.reduce(function (accumulator, page) {
        return accumulator.concat(page.txns.map(function(txn){ 
                return {
                    page: txn.page_idx,
                    txn: txn.grade ? page.txns.indexOf(txn) : 0,
                    virtual: !txn.grade
                }
        })) ;
    }, []);
},
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/c5euynqL/)

Comment: In the fiddle some of the objects have txn: > 0 and show virtual: true, did you intend to write  virtual: !txn.grade ?

Comment: Yes sure, I just confused the logic because I have no idea about the business logic you apply and it is not important in terms of the question. I filled page objects randomly just with the fields I saw in your snippet. I provided just the skeleton for transformation not the true algorythm you can copy and paste in your app

Comment: This doesn't work in this particular case because virtual is set to true when page is empty, in other words we put virtual in pages where there is no txn at all.

Comment: @BarryG could extend your question with a subset of real data so that we could discuss on exact example? So far I've located and fixed only one inconsistency about calculating the resulting index `txn`. In OP it's `0` for virtual nodes

Comment: I have added the data schema.

Comment: There is [no difference](http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/c5euynqL/1/) in result of two methods for this sample data.

Comment: See this version, there is a difference between the for loop and reduce: http://jsfiddle.net/c5euynqL/2/

Comment: Oh, well you've change the algorithm. Now for pages with empty `txns` there is a value returned. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/c5euynqL/3/) is how you can do it

Comment: Don't think its correct, because the declarative version produces a different ouput from the for loop

Comment: @BarryG are you looking at the latest [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/c5euynqL/3/)? Cause it's showing me same three pages with a sequence of `page` and `txn=0` and `virtual=1`

Comment: You are correct, but the reduce-map does not work in the case where grade in data >0, example: http://jsfiddle.net/c5euynqL/4/

Comment: You should define exactly possible input and desired output. The last change you applied to `for` method changed the logic in such a way that now `txns` with `grade=0` inside a page with other `txns` with higher `grade` are not added as virtual. They are not added at all. http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/c5euynqL/5/

Comment: Unless the fiddle changed since you posted it, I'm getting different outputs using the reduce vs for-loop. reduce:   {
        "page": 0,
        "txn": 0,
        "virtual": true
    },

The for-loop does not produce this object.

Comment: Yes exactly, that's what I meant. The previous change done by you in version http://jsfiddle.net/c5euynqL/2/ breaks the logic (if I understand the logic correctly)

Comment: Yes, the logic is correct in the last version for nested for loop, but not the reduce-map, looking for a way to convert that for loop in to something declarative. http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/c5euynqL/5/

Comment: Its not clear why does reduce-map produce an additional transaction at index 0?

Comment: Because for-loop ignore txns that have grade=0 and these txn has siblings. However when there is a single txn with grade=0 or page with no txns for-loop pushes a default (virtual=false) one

Comment: So what would the declarative version of the for-loop given the exact functionality you described above?

Comment: If latest fiddle represents the correct logic in for-loop then it's possible to add a [filter](http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/c5euynqL/16/) to reduce-map to match this logic